# How to Hard Set the Parent Page in Template

Tags: child-pages

This template displays child pages of the parent page that calls it.  I need to modify it to hard code the parent page to a specific parent, using the slug or other means.  Once I know how to do that I think I can then have the template display (in separate divs) the child pages from two different parents.  Can anyone get me started on how to hard-set the parent page?

thanks

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Portfolio Section
*/

get_header();

global $post;
?>
<h3><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h3>
<div class="port_sec_container">
<?php
$items = get_pages( array('sort_order' => 'ASC', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'child_of' => $post->ID ) );
foreach( $items as $item ) : ?>
<div class="port_sec_item">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($item->ID); ?>">
    <?php 
    $photosToShow = rand(1,3);
    $images = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => $photosToShow, 'post_parent' => $item->ID, 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'post_type' => 'attachment' ) );
    foreach( $images as $image ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'Portfolio-Thumb' );
    }
    ?>
    </a>
    <a href="<?php echo $item->guid; ?>"><h4><?php echo $item->post_title; ?>    </h4></a>
    <a href="<?php echo $item->guid; ?>"><h5><?php $fields = get_fields($item-    >ID); echo $fields['location']; ?></h5></a>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
portSecInit();
});
</script>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `'child_of' => $post->ID` argument to `'child_of' => 61`, or whatever the ID of the parent page is.

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I was looking for, I'll try it out and report back, thanks